# JavaFX 8 multiple bi-directional bindings

Tags: binding, javafx

My borderpane on the right contains a TextField. The center contains a draggable StackPane. I'm trying to bind the layoutX of the stackpane with the textfield. However, since I'm using MVP, there is a model (controller) in-between.

The text field (called 'idTopX' which comes from an FXML layout) has this binding to the model

```
idTopX.textProperty().bindBidirectional(model.topXProperty);
```

where model.topXProperty is defined as:

```
public StringProperty topXProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();
```

In turn the model binds its topXProperty to the draggable pane:

```
StringConverter<Number> converter = new NumberStringConverter();
Bindings.bindBidirectional(topXProperty, dragPane.xProperty, converter);
```

and finally the draggable pane has:

```
public DoubleProperty xProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
```

with the appropriate getters and setters for the property linked to the pane's layoutX.

So I have this big chain of bi-directional bindings TextField <-> model <--> draggable Pane <--> pane.layoutXProperty

It works while dragging the pane around, but as soon as the textfield is altered I get:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Bidirectional binding failed, setting to the previous value
```

Nothing in the stack trace points me back to my source and with the 'cryptic' message 'binding failed', I'm clutching at straws. Any suggestions? I'm also open to better implementations, because I suspect that my approach may also not be correct.

Comment: Update: by checking the complete stack trace (the ...59 more bit), I also see a "bound value cannot be set" message

Comment: Sounds like you may have used `bind` instead of `bindBidirectional` somewhere

Comment: You are so right! I did quite a bit of hacking after I not being happy with part of my design and accidentally left a 'bind' behind. I just didn't see it!